# Detecting page scroll/ current section being viewed in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

My page is divided into sections : #page-1 and #page-2

See Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/RZJLmsWDfs63dC0QuDJi

```
<body>
    <section id="page-1">
       This is page 1. It takes the whole height of the browser. User has to scroll down to see page-2.
     </section>

    <section id="page-2">
       <span class="animated bounce">This is page 2  </span>       
     </section>
</body>
```

Animation classes are being applied to different elements in #page-2.
However by the time the user scrolls down to these elements, the animation has already finished. Hence they just look like static objects.

Is there anyway I can detect when #page-2 is currently being viewed and then call a function to addClass('animated bounce') to certain elements ?

I would like to achieve this in angularjs if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a angularjs directive that is probably helpfull for you in this case. [Inview](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview) tries to solve this exact problem by reporting to you if a dom element is visible on the screen. Unfortunately I have been unable to test my solution because I couldn't find a minified js file of Inview but I assembled some code that should work:

```
<section id="page-2" in-view="{$inview ? isFocused=true;}">

   <div ng-class="{'animated bounce': isFocused}">This is page 2 </div>

</section>
```

The `$inview` is supposed to be true whenever the element is in visible in the browser. This leads to the scope variable `isFocused` being set to true and therefor the animation class is added to your div.

This should work as you have intended in your question, if it does not work for some reason please let me know so I can improve my answer.